# how to check the size and dimension of file size react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, filesize

Hy, I'm getting the details from API in which image is also coming but how I can check the size and dimension of the file. I'm fetching the data using Axios?

Comment: does the API return an URL for the picture?

Comment: yes @AmirSaadallah

Answer (score 1):

Since your API returns a URI you can use the Image component to get the dimensions

```
Image.getSize(uri, (width, height)=>console.log(width,height))
```

for the size , you can use fetch or Axios with the image URI then check the request returned. you can add that directly after you get the image URI

```
fetch(uri).then(response => console.log(response.headers.get("content-length")))
```

Comment: is Image that react-native component which use like <Image/>?

Comment: request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") => where I need to add this in API?

Comment: yeap the same component.
i update the response

Comment: I'm little confuse i get the data using axio({ }).then().catch() so according to you  this then function I Use console.log(response.headers.get("content-length"))?

Comment: both lines I provide will take place inside your Axios then

Comment: response.headers.get("content-length") this giving me 881

Answer (score 0):

you can get your image size by using this code

```
const myUri= "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_960_720.png";
Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height)=>console.log("image size",width,"x",height))
```